# Drop-down menu, redirect dynamically to a link based on choice. When submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, web, redirect, web-development-server

**The change required in home page search form:** 
For example, if I search for an investment advisor in Bengaluru,

**right now it shows the URL:** 
https://finvizer.com/?swoof=1&post_type=product&product_cat=investment-advisor-bengaluru

**This need to change to:**
https://finvizer.com/investment-advisers-in-bengaluru/

Code:
**First one is in functions.php**

```
        <div class="header-search-form"> 
            <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
```

now in this peice of code, method is get and what action doing is: calling the home url of the website(i.e. http://finvizer.com) and onsubmit the function is called serch_validate_home(), which is working fine.

```
    ?>" name="serchvalidformhome" id="serchvalidformhome" onsubmit="return serch_validate_home();"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="swoof" id="swoofhm" value="1" /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_typehm" value="product" />
```

this inputs are form a plugin "woocommerce" which comes in url, because of this peice of code website is landing to https://finvizer.com/?swoof=1&post_type=product&product_cat=investment-advisor-bengaluru but i wanted page to be redirected https://finvizer.com/investment-advisers-in-bengaluru/

I have made them comment and tried to run and the result was http://www..finvizer.com/?product_cat=

```
                    <div class="i-would-lik-cls">      
                   <?php  $terms = get_terms( 'locationfilter',array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC')); ?>                    
                <span class="srch-frm-home-temp-one">I need a</span> 
                <select  id="servicehm" style="width:100%"> 
                    <option value="">Choose a Service...</option> 
                    <option value="financial-planner-">Financial Planner</option>        
                    <option value="investment-advisor-">Investment Adviser</option>                
                    <option value="wealth-advisor-">Wealth Adviser</option>                        
                </select >   
                </div>                   
                <span class="srch-frm-home-temp-two">in</span> 
                 <div class="annual-incom-cls">                   
                <select id="locationfilterhm" style="width:100%" "> 
                    <option value="">Location</option> 
                    <option value="ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>        
                    <option value="bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>                
                    <option value="chennai">Chennai</option> 
                    <option value="delhi">Delhi</option> 
                    <option value="gurgaon">Gurgaon</option> 
                    <option value="hyderabad">Hyderabad</option> 
                    <option value="indore">Indore</option>    
                    <option value="kolkata">Kolkata</option>    
                    <option value="kochi">Kochi</option>    
                    <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option> 
                    <option value="pune">Pune</option>                
                    <option value="surat">Surat</option>        
                </select >   
                </div>
```

so from here, I saw there is one more input product cat, I changed it nothing(input name="") than website was redirected to  https://finvizer.com/?

```
                <input name="product_cat" id="product_cathm" value="" type="hidden" />   
                <div class="prod-serh"> 
                    <button type="submit">search</button> 
                </div> 

            </form> 
        </div>            
    </div>   

</div> 
<div style="clear:both;"></div> 
     <?php    
$ReturnString = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); return $ReturnString; 
   }
```

The second one is in **footer.php**
 it's a javascript code in footer.php. This function is called by functions.php
Here two variable are taking value from the form, **the service value is in ser** and **location one is in loct**.

```
   function serch_validate_home(){ 
     var ser = jQuery("#servicehm").val(); 
     var loct = jQuery("#locationfilterhm").val(); 
       if( ser!='' && loct!=''){
```

**in this srch variable, I have already placed "in-" .** it made the srch variable vale what we want (i.e. financial-planner-in-bengaluru). 
but it's not working without those two HTML embedded inputs which I mentioned above. And when I try with them the page gets crashed.

```
         var srch =ser+loct; 
           jQuery("#product_cathm").val(srch); 
           document.serchvalidformhome.submit(); 
             } 
           return false; 
              }
```

p.s. this code is written by another developer, which the owner has no contact with, I have been asked to redirect the page on a different link. I tried to go through each and every step as per my knowledge but got stuck.
**I was able to remove everything from the link and was able to redirect to** 
https://finvizer.com/?
but how should I place **that srch varable** instead of that "?"

Comment: If you're expecting someone to just do this for you, you're in the wrong place.  If you have a specific question about an attempt that you've made, then you need to do a better job describing how the result of your attempt failed to do what you wanted and what debugging you've already done.

Comment: I don't see any specific question, please be more specific.

Comment: I have tried to explain it more precisely, in a recent edit of the question.

Comment: @PatrickQ  it's my first question here, so made few mistakes while asking, I have made changes, please see and let me know your thoughts! Thank you once more.

Comment: @jesicadev18 made changes, please may have a look at it now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to activate first, put the "onsubmit" before "action" on the form.

Otherwise I think this question needs a little more info on the submit side.

```
function serch_validate_home(){ 
 var ser = jQuery("#servicehm").val(); 
 var loct = jQuery("#locationfilterhm").val(); 
   if((ser!='') && (loct!='')){ 
     var srch =ser+"in-"+loct; 
     jQuery("#product_cathm").val(srch); 
     document.serchvalidformhome.submit(); 
   } 
 return false; 
}
```

i would suggest adding the brakets and "in-" for srch? If this doesnt help please help me understand what the "action" in the form does as well as any other important informatino needed

Comment: Some changes have been made to the question, you may please have look at them. thank you! for investing your time in this question.